# jquery running in google app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have included the following jquery meta-tag to the new html5 file  as required by the new google apps script HTML service API , however it seemed that the jquery syntax is not working , as shown by below code snippet which display array return value from successful server call?

I still force to  format using standard css or HTML tag to generate the required output instead of much neat  jQuery syntax call.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" id='file_txt' size='100' value="" style="visibility:hidden" readonly/>


<p></p>

<a id="Hyperlink" style="visibility:hidden">File Location</a>
<script>
function  rep1(linkid){

//$("Hyperlink").show();

x=document.getElementById("Hyperlink");
x.style.visibility="visible";
x.href=linkid[1];
x.text="File HyperLink :"+linkid[0];

y=document.getElementById("file_txt");
y.value=linkid[2];
y.style.visibility='visible';
y.style.color='red';

}
google.script.run   
  .withSuccessHandler(rep1) 
  .onOpen1();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the documentation for HtmlService states that all recent JQuery libraries are compatible, I have had trouble with versions higher than 1.9.1.

Try:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

instead

Comment: This is still accurate as of 2015-06-28. If you try to include newer versions, jQuery just ends up undefined with no apparent errors, making this particularly hard to troubleshoot.